# Getting illegal state exception with spinner

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

Hi i am trying to a populate a spinner with strings using arrayadapter.but i am not able to do so as it throws illegalstateexception

Here is the code

```
   final Dialog dialog= new Dialog(SamplepaintActivity.this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.customhourdialog);

    Button OK,Cancel;

    OK = (Button)findViewById(R.id.OkButton);
    Cancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.CancelButton);

    ArrayAdapter <String> spinAdapter =
              new ArrayAdapter <String> (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item );
            spinAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinAdapter.add("Sample1");
            spinAdapter.add("Sample2");
            Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner.setAdapter(spinAdapter);

    Cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {



                dialog.dismiss();

         }});
    OK.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {



                dialog.dismiss();

         }});
    dialog.show();
```

THe exception is thrown in the line when i set the adapter for the spinner

This is the xml file of my customdialog

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">
     <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Begin" android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1" android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"></Button>
     <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/button2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="End" android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1" android:layout_marginLeft="56dp"></Button>
<TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Subject" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_below="@+id/button1" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_marginTop="39dp"></TextView>
<Spinner android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/spinner1" android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2">

</Spinner>

<TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Time" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_marginTop="20dp"></TextView>
<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/OkButton" android:layout_width="150dp" android:text="OK" android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_marginTop="53dp"></Button>
<Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Cancel" android:layout_width="150dp" android:id="@+id/CancelButton" android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/OkButton" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/OkButton" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"></Button>
```

Comment: instead of **CharSequence**, can you try with **String**

Comment: Where in your activity is this running?  It's not on a background thread is it?

Comment: @Waqas i tried that it doesn't work.

Comment: @Steve Danner no it isn't,my project file has only one activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the problem is in this line:

```
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

change **adapter** to **spinAdapter** and you should be good to go. see below:

```
spinAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

---

**updated**
you need to fix your Dialog building process. See below:

```
    AlertDialog.Builder bldr = new AlertDialog.Builder(SamplepaintActivity.this);
    LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.customhourdialog, null);

    bldr.setView(view);

    Button OK,Cancel;

    OK = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.OkButton);
    Cancel = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.CancelButton);
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter <String> spinAdapter = new ArrayAdapter <String> (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item );
    spinAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinAdapter.add("Sample1");
    spinAdapter.add("Sample2");
    spinner.setAdapter(spinAdapter);

    bldr.show();
```

Comment: there must be something else wrong in your code, paste your full code

Comment: i just updated my answer. You need to inflate your layout in to Dialog.Builder to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

First define spinner, then define the adapter. There after see where the error occurs. I guess error wont occur.